# ConnectTimeoutException infinispan

Tags: infinispan

During infinispan cache load randomly I am noticing below error message in my application logs:

> Cluster might have completely shutdown, try resetting transport layer and topology id
> io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: 172.XX.20.XX:11222

Checked `telnet nc -z ip 11222` is successful at that time, no error in infinispan server logs, number of connections to the server is also not very high.

Infinispan server version 9.4.11

Could anyone help me on what causing this?

Thanks,
Satyabrata Mohanty

Answer (score 0):

What are your Hot Rod client connection/socket timeout configurations ?

I would increase the connection timeout and see if it happens again. If the server is overloaded your connection timeout might not be enough.

Comment: connection timeout is 1 secs and read/socket timeout is 2secs